# How to scale Azure Eventhub Throughput Units with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, azure, servicebus, azure-eventhub

I would like to modify the number of Throughput Units with PowerShell:
[ServiceBus\EventHub\Scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78bxj.jpg)
I didn't find any relevant information about that.
Could you please help me which command should I use?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At one of the projects i wanted to implement the same, and what i have found is that only mention of the possibility to change it using (REST) API is on [that page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/event-hubs-overview/).
However, there is no such possibility listed:

1) In the [REST API specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790674.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

2) In the [Event Hubs SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs).

Which makes me believe that it is not possible at least with the Classic REST API.